# Getting access to varaibles when testing Vue with Jest

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs

I am using the structure below in my Vue.js web application. I am now trying to implement testing to it. But when trying to test the `exampleOfFunction` it says that `this.exampleOfData2` is `undefined`.

```js
<template>
      *Some HTML*
</template>

<script>
    *Some Imports*
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            exampleOfData1: [],
            exampleOfData2: 100
     },
        methods: {
        exampleOfFunction:function(){
            if(this.exampleOfData2 === 100)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        },
    created() {
    },
    mounted() {
    }
 }
</script>
```

In my testfile I then try to access the code above and I succeed with `console.log(FileToTest.data());` I can see the values of data and I can access the function with `FileToTest.methods.exampleOfFunction();` but when I call the function it says that `this.exampleOfData2` is `undefined`.

Comment: What exactly is `FileToTest`? In case this is component definition you've imported, you're testing it the wrong way. Vue binds methods to an instance while you're not doing this, there' not much value in tests that doesn't conform to real behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the component options definition instead of the component instance in your tests.

You should be creating a wrapper by [mounting the component](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount), and then you could access the component method via [`wrapper.vm`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#vm):

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import FileToTest from '@/components/FileToTest.vue'

describe('FileToTest', () => {
  it('exampleOfFunction returns false by default', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FileToTest)
    expect(wrapper.vm.exampleOfFunction()).toBe(false)
  })

  it('exampleOfFunction returns true when data is not 100', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FileToTest)
    wrapper.setData({ exampleOfData2: 0 })
    expect(wrapper.vm.exampleOfFunction()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```